# Profiling timer expired loop im bash shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am running the following program

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( x=1; x<=180; x++ ))
do
./speed && perl load_tables.pl && Rscript Test.R     
done
```

but after some loops I get the error

```
Profiling timer expired
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: It must have something to do with "some stuff". [Related?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42024496/profiling-timer-expired-when-using-gperftools-with-sort) [Or this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146082/valgrind-profiling-timer-expired)

Comment: @Aaron thanks for your reply but I don't think so, since once it stops I can  make it run again from the point it stopped...

Comment: Still, you should post what "some stuff" is if you can. It looks like it can be raised by `make` when it receives a `SIGPROF`, but it could be another software for another reason. `SIGPROF` is related to profiling, the loop you posted can't be responsible for it alone (although it is plausible that it won't happen if "some stuff" is only executed once). Are you maybe `time`ing your execution?

Comment: @Aaron thanks. Some stuff is a combination of .cxx programs and R scripts. I am not sure if I am timing it, how can I check?

Comment: Ok I saw your edit, and it's very lickely that `speed` is raising or catching the SIGPROF since it sounds related to profiling. Now I don't know this binary, but someone might be able to help now

Comment: @ Aaron no it's some program I wrote, but in the loop I am calling more of them. The weird thing is that if I run it different times it stops at different steps (x=10, x=15, etc..) in the loop..

Comment: Ok, I understand why you didn't post it at first ! I would suggest trying to isolate the error to `speed` (or the others if it fails), maybe by invoking it in a loop where it only `speed` and `sleep` ? Once you confirm the source of your problem, then you'll be able to ask for help debugging it by posting its code here

Comment: I won't be able to help any further, I suck at `c++`, `perl` and `R`. Good luck !

Comment: @Aaron thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You can make your script ignore the SIGPROF signal by adding this command at the top:

> trap "" SIGPROF

This registers a signal handler for SIGPROF that does nothing (the empty string).